# How to point Site5 domain name to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I am trying to point custom domain name from Site5 to heroku domain. I am following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Inside my Site5 control panel I choose Advanced DNS Zone Editor and inserted the following values:

```
Record type: CNAME
Record name: www
CNAME host: stark-plains-xxx.herokuapp.com
```

I saved those values but there is no change when I access my site www.mysite.com. There is still default index on front page.

Command `host www.mysite.com` only gives an IP address of my site.

Have I done everything correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to answer my own question. That process I described is correct for `www`. It just needs a little bit more time to get it work.

So, for `www.mysite.com` these are correct values inside Site5 control panel -> `Advanced DNS Zone Editor`:

```
Record type: CNAME
Record name: www
CNAME host: stark-plains-xxx.herokuapp.com
```

For `mysite.com`, procedure is a little bit different because you can't delete default values. In this case simple redirect is needed. On Site5 dashboard we need to choose `Domains -> URL Redirects` and put the following values:

[image]

That's it. Now both `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com` will redirect to our site hosted on Heroku.

Comment: Interesting to note that if you're using `https` the forward from the naked domain to `www` will fail SSL cert checks since the forward works only for `http`. There is some more discussion in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains